# how to handle sessions on socket.io in a separate server when user refresh page

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, socket.io

i have a project runing a front-end separated by the server with socket.io and i'm having some problem to handle session , whats the correct way to handle sessions in socket io, when the user refresh the page it looses the session and changes the socket witch is really bad, whats the right way in this aproach
?

Comment: You should cookie your session so when the page is refreshed, you can reattach to the same session via cookie when the socket reconnects after the reload.  When a socket.io connection connects, it has access to all cookies for that page.

Comment: Do you have `login` in your system ? How do you recognize which user is `connected` ?

Comment: In all of the ways you have to store user data either at client end using localStorage or server end.

Comment: yes, how can i implement it using cookies can you guys show me an example?, and how can i let it expire after a determined date , i have a login in my sistem witch i populate an array users[] in the express app

Answer (score 0):

When socketio event is triggered, also store the data into your backend server, and after refresh page, use some ajax call to retrieve data should be able to work.

Comment: can you show an example using socket io and express